# NSFileManager finds files inside a folder only when it's running under a debugger

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, filesystems, nsfilemanager

When I run the following code under the Xcode debugger it successfully finds the package with .app extension, but when I run it standalone "file" object is nil. In fact when I did NSLogs folderEnum was also nil. Note that folderPath points to a folder that is in the same directory as the the program executable.

```
NSFileManager *localFileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *folderEnum = [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:folderPath];
NSString *file;
while (file = [folderEnum nextObject]) {
  if ([[file pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"app"]) {
     break;
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Something to do with the Mac system file permissions?

**Edit**

I should have probably mentioned that folderPath was actually a relative path and not an absolute one. So I changed folderPath to be relative to [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] path and it works now. But if anyone can shed some light why relative path doesn't work that be great.

Answer (score 1):

Does changing the first line to:

`NSFileManager *localFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];`

make any difference? Are you just trying to get the path for your application? (There are easier ways)

Comment: That didn't help. It seems to me all file system operations are failing. In fact NSTask launch is also falling, it returns "launch path not accessible" even when I hard code the launch path. Of course all of these work fine under debugger. Just to give you an idea what I'm working on, I'm creating a custom installer which executes various installers and performs file system operations.

Comment: You haven't enabled entitlements (i.e. Sandboxing) by accident have you?

Comment: I checked that earlier and entitlements are definitely disabled. It does seem like a Sandboxing type issue though. But yeah Enable Entitlements is unchecked.

Comment: I created a new empty Project in Xcode 4.2 and just pasted the above code (with NSLogs) in applicationDidFinishLaunching selector. Same deal, works under the debugger only.